# use hash symbol(#) in .conf

Tags: configuration

I need to use a hash symbol(#) in a .conf file. How can I do that? All my parsers are considering lines # symbol as commented. One of my data has # in it.

Eg:
TEST1 = ASD#ABC

Answer (score 4):

There are several flavors of `.conf` files. Please specify what are you trying to configure for more precise answer.

[Wikipedia article on INI files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INI_file#Escape_characters) suggests backslash escaping.

> \#   Number sign

However, there is a different solution for otherwise very similar [MySQL config file](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/option-files.html). Backslash escaping doesn't work there.

> You can optionally enclose the value within single quotation marks or double quotation marks, which is useful if the value contains a “#” comment character.